# Chrome Dev Tools: Breakpoints Disappear?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I'm having some trouble with chrome dev tools JavaScript breakpoints. I'm debugging a 3rd party javascript file and I'm setting debug points manually (not using `debugger;`)

However, if I close dev tools, and reopen it, my set breakpoints are no longer there. Clean slate. Sometimes they are, sometimes not.

How do I force chrome browser to keep all breakpoints I set for a particular script? I'm talking about these breakpoints:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest copying and hosting that file yourself and adding the `debuggers` wherever you want so that you don't depend on Chrome devtools keeping track of them.